# Jersey test fail for endpoint which don't need role (is not annotated with @RolesAllowed)

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I have following base resource (endpoint) test class.

```
public abstract class AbstractResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    private static final String PORT = "9991";

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        forceSet(TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT, PORT);
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

        final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig().packages(
                "com.intouch.api.rest",
                "com.intouch.api.security")
                .register(createMoxyJsonResolver())
                .register(SecurityEntityFilteringFeature.class)
                .property("jersey.config.server.tracing.type", "ALL")
                .property("jersey.config.server.tracing.threshold", "TRACE")
                .property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);

        return ServletDeploymentContext
                .forServlet(new ServletContainer(config))
                .addListener(ContextLoaderListener.class)
                .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext-api-test.xml")
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
        super.configureClient(config);
        config.register(GsonJsonObjectProvider.class)
                .register(GsonJsonArrayProvider.class);
    }
}
```

It's working perfect for tests, which needs role (annotated with @RolesAllowed). But I have some endpoints, which don't need roles. This tests are failing because of for them are check the role of previous test (for example previous test is calling an endpoint which needs MANAGE role,  next test is calling an endpoint which don't need any role and for this (second test) is calling securityContext.isUserInRole("MANAGE")).
Is it bug or it should be like this?
How we can fix it?

This is an example of resource (endpoint):

```
@Path("/users")
@Component
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceFacade userServiceFacade;

    @POST
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public UserAccountBean createUser(UserAccountBean userAccountBean) {
           return userServiceFacade.createUser(userAccountBean);
    }

    @PUT
    @RolesAllowed({Permission.Constants.MANAGE_USERS_VALUE})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public UserAccountBean updateUser(UserAccountBean userAccountBean) {
           return userServiceFacade.updateUser(userAccountBean);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example resource class(es) that this issue occurs with.

Comment: @peeskillet I added an example of resource into the description above.

Comment: So `updataUser` works, but `createUser` doesn't?

Comment: Yes, updateUser works, but createUser not. If I comment updateUser and run the test again createUser will work. I debug the Jesey codes, when updateUser test commented/removed createUser is working, because in the session Jesey doesn't have any previous roles. If you had a look to Jesey codes you can see this commnet in SecurityServerScopeProvider.getFilteringScopes mthod:           // Get all roles collected from entities and check with current security context.